# Is there a sequence whose set of subsequential limits is $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Is there a sequence whose set of subsequential limits is $[0,1]$?

My guess is yes: I tried $s_n = |\cos n|$. It makes since intuitively that all the subsequences hit every number in $[0, 1]$ but I am having trouble proving this rigorously.

Comment: Consider enumerating $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$.

Comment: Jut a slight note: your function doesn't hit *every* number in $[0,1]$ -- eg, doesn't hit $0$ or $1$. Certainly hits a dense set, and most likely a set of full Lebesgue measure (ie "almost everything"). Note that *every* point in $[0,1]$ has a subsequence that has that point as it's limit. So the closure is $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$s_1=0/1$,

$s_2=0/2, s_3=1/2,$

$s_4=0/4, s_5=1/4, s_6=2/4, s_7=3/4$

$s_8=0/8, s_9=1/8, s_{10}=2/8, s_{11}=3/8, s_{12}=4/8, s_{13}=5/8, s_{14}=6/8, s_{15}=7/8,...$
 so on and so forth.

Notice that $s_{2^n}=0$ and $s_{2^n+k}=k/2^n$ until $k$ gets as big as $2^n$, which then that equals to $s_{2^{n+1}}=0$

So this allows you to explicitly write out $s_n$ (not necessary for the proof)

take any $L \in [0,1]$. $\cfrac{a_n}{2^n}\leq L<\cfrac{a_n+1}{2^n}$ for any $n$, $a_n$ being some integer

pick the subsequence $\bigg(\cfrac{a_n}{2^n}\bigg)$, this subsequence converges to $L$

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how this sequence has the desired property though? Could you provide proof that the subsequential limits hit every point in $[0, 1]$.

Comment: I added explaination to my answer, does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Yes, it's very helpful, but I'm curious as to how I can write an expression for $s_n$ explicitly.

Comment: I just modified my answer to provide an explicit formula for $s_n$

Comment: question, what is $a_n$?

Comment: $a_n$ is some unique integer such that $\cfrac{a_n}{2^n}\leq L<\cfrac{a_n+1}{2^n}$ . for example, if $L = 5/7$, for $n=8$ we have $5/8<5/7<6/8$, so $a_8=5$

Comment: @Morewaterplz, what if $L=\pi/4 $? Then what will be $a_n$?

Answer (score 3):

For this problem, I will suggest tackling a different problem first:
What are the properties of the set of limit points?
Hint: It's a closed set.

This makes the problem a little bit easier, all you need to do is find a sequence whose limit points form a dense set in [0,1].

Building such sequence is quite intuitive: Take for instance the sequence 
$a_1 = 1 , a_2 = 1/2$
$ a_3 = 1, a_4 = 2/3, a_5 = 1/2, a_6 = 1/3$

$ a_7 =1 \dots$

Edit: Btw: there is a beautiful theorem (I think by d'Alembert) stating:

> THM: Let $\alpha \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$. Then the set $ \{n\alpha -[n\alpha ]\colon n\in \mathbb N\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

$n\alpha -[n\alpha ] = \{n\alpha\}$ is the fractional part of $n\alpha$.

Comment: This is similar to the answer, but I can't see how it actually has the desired properties.

Comment: @MathMajor , i added more numbers to the sequence. As you can see - every rational number appears infinitely many times - therefore every rational number is a limit point.

Comment: What about the irrationals in $[0, 1]$?

Comment: @MathMajor for that you need to prove the first (*easy*) lemma i suggested.